# Error when start to attach mdf - : parameter name: ncolindex actual value was -1 (Microsoft.Sql Server.Grid Control)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Got the following error when first attempted to attach a database

> parameter name: ncolindex actual value was -1 (Microsoft.Sql Server.Grid Control)

What does this mean and how do I correct ?

Answer (score -2):

Try to login with Admin account (not sql account)

Comment: What is Admin account?

Comment: Admin account mean login with Window Authentication mode . Not sql server authen. This error happen usually because your account don't have permission to do something